How do Christian apologists defend the author of Hebrews changing the words of Jeremiah 31?
 Related: Why does the author of Hebrews render their quotation of Jeremiah 31:33 differently in two places?
Background
The book of Hebrews uses the Hebrew Bible as support for its arguments many times. The author cites Jeremiah 31:33 in two different places and chooses to render the verse curiously differently each time.
The first citation occurs in Hebrews 8:10:

ὅτι αὕτη ἡ διαθήκη ἣν διαθήσομαι τῷ οἴκῳ Ἰσραὴλ μετὰ τὰς ἡμέρας ἐκείνας, λέγει Κύριος, διδοὺς νόμους μου εἰς τὴν διάνοιαν αὐτῶν, καὶ ἐπὶ καρδίας αὐτῶν ἐπιγράψω αὐτούς, καὶ ἔσομαι αὐτοῖς εἰς Θεόν καὶ αὐτοὶ ἔσονταί μοι εἰς λαόν. (NA27)
For this is the covenant that I will make with the house of Israel after that time, declares the Lord: I will put my laws in their minds and write them on their hearts. I will be their God, and they will be my people.

The second citation is in Hebrews 10:16:

Αὕτη ἡ διαθήκη ἣν διαθήσομαι πρὸς αὐτοὺς μετὰ τὰς ἡμέρας ἐκείνας, λέγει Κύριος· διδοὺς νόμους μου ἐπὶ καρδίας αὐτῶν, καὶ ἐπὶ τὴν διάνοιαν αὐτῶν ἐπιγράψω αὐτούς (NA27)
This is the covenant I will make with them after those days, says the Lord: I will put My laws on their hearts and write them on their minds

For reference, Jeremiah 31:33 reads

כִּי זֹאת הַבְּרִית אֲשֶׁר אֶכְרֹת אֶת־בֵּית יִשְׂרָאֵל אַחֲרֵי
הַיָּמִים הָהֵם נְאֻם־יְהֹוָה נָתַתִּי אֶת־תּוֹרָתִי בְּקִרְבָּם
וְעַל־לִבָּם אֶכְתְּבֶנָּה וְהָיִיתִי לָהֶם לֵאלֹהִים וְהֵמָּה
יִהְיוּ־לִי לְעָם׃ (MT)
But such is the covenant I will make with the House of Israel after these days—declares Hashem: I will put My Torah into their inmost being and inscribe it upon their hearts. Then I will be their G-d, and they shall be My people.

Definitions
The definition of misquoting is to repeat something someone has said in a way that is not accurate.
Question
Which of the two citations is the accurate one? Is this an example of misquoting the Hebrew bible? Why does the author of Hebrews use "house of Israel" the first time and "them" the second time?

Septuagint also appears to use "house of Israel" but in any case, this seems to be a non-issue. There isn't evidence that the NT writers followed modern anti-plagarism conventions. Quotation marks weren't in use, plus substituting the appropriate pronoun is hardly "misquoting"; the author doesn't even refer to Jeremiah by name.

This video gives a good overview of the standards of citation used in 1st Century Judaism: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c2I6KgoLSIs

The speaker recommends as a resource, "The Commentary of the New Testament Use of the Old Testament" edited by Beale and Carson.

Thanks @PaulChernoch, an answer explaining those two sources would definitely answer the question

As Koine Greek expresses concept by first labelling it (anarthrously and with a noun) then afterward referring to that location with the article (which is derived from the demonstrative pronoun) so, in this case, having once defined concept (house of Israel) thereafter the syntax locates the pronoun to that defined concept. This is not a question about apology or defence of apology. It is a question about Greek grammar and should, perhaps, be on SE-BH rather than here.

Why does this question even matter. It isn't the main focus of the prophecy...the main focus of the prophecy is that God has written His laws on OUR Hearts and in OUR minds. The point is, ALL are without excuse knowing right from wrong.  There isnt even a contradiction in your reference. This is only an issue for Sunday worshipping denominations who think there are two covenants of the law. There aren't, the law is still just as relevant as its always been! No one has ever been saved by the law...thats not its purpose!

@adam the main focus of the prophecy is that God has written His laws on OUR Hearts and in OUR minds - the covenant in Jeremiah 31 is apparently between Israel and YHVH. Broadening the covenant the way Hebrews does is an innovation not found in the Hebrew bible

@AviAvraham and who is spiritual Israel? Is not the gospel also applicable to the gentiles? The plan of salvation is for all the world. The God of love, author of the ten commandments, sent His son to make aronement on the cross for the wages of sin is death, so that all mankind may he saved. If your claim the Mosaic law is only for Israel, then why do you need Christs atoning Sacrifice? NO LAW=NO SIN=NO JUDGEMENT. One cannot be judged when there are no standards by which judgement can be made.

It should be obvious that we cannot be saved by keeping the law because we have already sinned and are therefore condemned by it. However that does not mean the moral standard is irrelevant or not applicable to everyday Christian life. There is a simple test... If you are not under the law, go and break one of the commandments and see how long it is before "the law" or "morality" comes after you!

From "Commentary on the New Testament use of the Old Testament", page 970, edited by G. K. Beale and D. A. Carson, 2007,

The quotation of Jeremiah 31:31-34, the longest OT quotation in the NT, plays a vital role in the book's discourse on Christ's superior high-priestly offering (Hebrews 8:3-10:18), laying the groundwork for the climax of the book's christological exposition. Through the use of this rich prophetic passage [in Jeremiah], the author establishes the superiority of the new covenant (8:7-13) prior to addressing the superiority of the new-covenant [sacrificial] offering (9:1-10:18).

I think it is easy to see that, having quoted Jeremiah fully once in 8:10-12, there is no need to do so (fully) again.
The first quotation is used to appeal to Jeremiah to the truth of the doctrine that is going to be established in the on-going Hebrews discourse, including that there is a new covenant that proves that the old is redundant, because it was ineffective.
Having laid out the argument in 8:13-10:14, the author, to finish the section, summarises its conclusions, and makes a second appeal to Jeremiah as evidence that the Holy Spirit confirms those conclusions.
(In his second quote he may be appealing to the reader to observe that in interpretting the passage of Jeremiah he has used reliable exegesis rather than eisegesis: the whole section is anchored in an accurate exegesis of Jeremiah 31:31-34.)
And the conclusions are that the old covenant with its sacrifices of the blood of bulls and goats is no longer needed, because in the new covenant "their sins and iniquities" God "will remember no more".  And "where remission of these is, there is no more offering for sin".  The old covenant is made redundant by the replacement of the new, which is far better.
The second appeal is thus a fitting conclusion to this section of Hebrews.

The Old covenant wasn't changed because the law was ineffective. It was changed because mankind didn't keep his end of the bargain. That's exactly what Jeremiah and Hebrews tells us. In the new covenant IT IS GOD WHO MAKES AND KEEPS THE PROMISE NOT MANKIND. That's why the law isn't on tablets of stone anymore, it's in our hearts and minds and that's the whole point! (This is so simple I cannot understand how people miss this)

The Old Covenant wasn't changed at all.. it was replaced.

@Adam - "For it is not possible that the blood of bulls and goats should take away sins", 10:4.  The old covenant was "ineffective". It was never designed to be anything else. It did not make those under it capable of keeping its terms.
